# MultiValueDictKeyError in accessing same form element in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have some dropdowns here in my Index.html file. I have accessed the values selected in `name=player1` and `name=player2` dropdowns. But when I am going to access the value of `name=selectcountry1` on same page in same form. Django is showing `MultiValueDictKeyError`. If I comment out the line in which I am accessing `name=selectcountry1`, all works fine. It takes the values of other dropdowns correctly.

Also when I use `request.POST.get('selectcountry1')`, it is returning 'None', What is the problem as well as the solution. I don't want None, I want the value selected in dropdown.

My HTML Page -

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'dynamic' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{% csrf_token %}
{% comment %} Defining a Form for Accepting first and second country and submit button {% endcomment %}

<!--Defining Left Division for Team 1 (team1div)-->
<div style="float : left; margin-top: 2%; width: 50%; padding-left: 10px;">
<div style="margin-left: 15px;">
<select name="selectcountry1" id="c1" onchange="getValue1(this)" style="width:180px;">

<option class="sel" selected value="select">Select Country 1</option>
<option data-img_src='/static/India.png'  value="India" >India</option>
<option  data-img_src='/static/Australia.png' value="Australia" >Australia</option>
<option data-img_src='/static/England.png' value="England" >England</option>
<option data-img_src='/static/NewZealand.png' value="NewZealand" >New Zealand</option>
<option data-img_src='/static/SouthAfrica.png' value="SouthAfrika" >South Afrika</option>
<option  data-img_src='/static/WestIndies.png' value="WestIndies" >West Indies</option>
<option data-img_src='/static/Pakistan.png' value="Pakistan" >Pakistan</option>
<option data-img_src='/static/Srilanka.png' value="SriLanka" >Sri Lanka</option>
<option data-img_src='/static/Bangladesh.png' value="Bangladesh" >Bangladesh</option>
<option data-img_src='/static/Afganistan.jpg'  value="Afganistan" >Afganistan</option>


 </select>
  </div>

  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  


<!--select01-->
<select name="player1" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="background-color: #5959a6; width: 165px;  margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 40px; margin-bottom: 20px;">

  <!--INDIA-->
  <option class="sel" value="0" selected>Select Player 1</option>
  
  <option class="ind" value="4063">Yuzvendra Chahal</option>
  <option class="ind" value="3644">Ravindra Jadeja</option>
  <option class="ind" value="3991">Bhuvneshwar Kumar</option>
  <option class="ind" value="4083">Manish Pandey</option>
  <option class="ind" value="4137">K L Rahul</option>

</select>

<select name="player2" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="background-color: #5959a6; width: 165px;  margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 40px; margin-bottom: 20px;">

  <!--INDIA-->
  <option class="sel" value="0" selected>Select Player 2</option>
   <option class="ind" value="4063">Yuzvendra Chahal</option>
  <option class="ind" value="3644">Ravindra Jadeja</option>
  <option class="ind" value="3991">Bhuvneshwar Kumar</option>
  <option class="ind" value="4083">Manish Pandey</option>
  <option class="ind" value="4137">K L Rahul</option>
</select>
```

My views.py -

```
def dynamic(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        count01 = request.POST['selectcountry1']

        p1 = request.POST['player1']
        p2 = request.POST['player2']

        winning_percentage_of_countries = {
                'p1' : p1,
                'p2' : p2,
                'country01' : count01,
        }

    return render(request, "dynamic.html", context=winning_percentage_of_countries)
```

My urls.py -

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name='home'),
    path("about/", views.about, name='about'),
    path("dynamic/", views.dynamic, name='dynamic'),
]
```

[image: Error code]